# Why does my program exit when calling Printf not working through LuaJIT FFI?

Tags: c, lua, printf, ffi, luajit

I have been trying to load a very simple DLL through the LuaJIT FFI library, but when my code runs, the program pauses for a second and then quits without any error message halfway through as soon as it tries to run printf.

My DLL's code:

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) int getnumber(){
    return 4000;
}

__declspec(dllexport) void doprintf(){
    printf("hello from printf!");
}

__declspec(dllexport) const char* returnstring(const char*source){
    
    return source;

}


int main()
{
    
}
```

My main.lua:

```lua
print('hello from lua!') --> hello from lua!
local ffi = require("ffi")
ffi.cdef[[
  
  int getnumber();
  
  void doprintf();
  
  const char* returnstring(const char*source);
  
]]
clib = ffi.load("my-dll")

print('libraries loaded.') --> libraries loaded.
print(ffi.string(clib.returnstring('string test'))) --> string test
print(clib.getnumber() - 1)  --> 3999
print(clib.doprintf())  --> hello from printf!
print('done!!') --> done!!
```

What happens when I run it:

```
C:\Users\DPS2004\OneDrive\Documents\ffitest>ls
main.lua    my-dll.dll

C:\Users\DPS2004\OneDrive\Documents\ffitest>luajit main.lua
hello from lua!
libraries loaded.
string test
3999

C:\Users\DPS2004\OneDrive\Documents\ffitest>
```

Comment: No idea if it is related, but C functions that don't take parameters should be defined as `foo(void)`

Comment: @EugeneSh. just tried adding voids to getnumber and doprintf, the program still exits after printing 3999

Comment: Do `luajit.exe` and your DLL depend on the same CRT?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I tried rebuilding luajit.exe from the source, but still got the same results, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Try to append `\n` to `"hello from printf!"`

Comment: Still no luck, sorry.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that, your code works fine here. Compiled with `cl my-dll.c /MT /link /DLL /out:my-dll.dll`

Comment: do you think you could send me a link to the compiled DLL?